# MySQL max difference between 2 different days for same column

Tags: mysql

I have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `points` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`latitude` decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
`longitude` decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
`weight` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now I want to calculate the max weight difference between 2 different days grouped by their latitude and longitude (return latitude, longitude, max weight diff). Any idea please?

An Example as follow (assuming I want to calculate the difference between 8/2/2015 and 8/3/2015)

```
id  |   date    | latitude | longitude | weight
-----------------------------------------------
1   | 8/2/2015  | 11111    | 22222     | 12
2   | 8/2/2015  | 11111    | 22222     | 8
3   | 8/2/2015  | 66666    | 88888     | 10
4   | 8/3/2015  | 11111    | 22222     | 5
5   | 8/3/2015  | 66666    | 88888     | 3
```

The returning tuple should be:

```
latitude | longitude | weight
-----------------------------
11111    | 22222     | 15
```

Comment: Are you taking the difference between the aggregate `SUM()` for the two days? Such that (12+8) - (5) = 15? What if more dates appear between - is it the difference only in the endpoint dates you are concerned with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and save yourself a join and aggregation:

```
select p.*, abs(weight1 - weight2) as diff
from (select latitude, longitude,
             sum(case when date = '2015-08-02' then weight else 0 end) as weight1,
             sum(case when date = '2015-08-03' then weight else 0 end) as weight2
      from points p
      where date in ('2015-08-02', '2015-08-03')
      group by latitude, longitude
     ) ll
order by diff desc
limit 1;
```

I'd like to note that you can do this without the subquery as well:

```
      select latitude, longitude,
             abs(sum(case when date = '2015-08-02' then weight 
                          when date = '2015-08-03' then - weight
                          else 0
                      end) ) as diff
      from points p
      where date in ('2015-08-02', '2015-08-03')
      group by latitude, longitude
      order by diff desc
      limit 1;
```

Also, I'm using `abs()`, because your question suggests that you only care about the magnitude of the difference, not the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries to get the sums of the weights for each coordinate on each day. Then join then, subtract the weights, and use `ORDER BY` to find the maximum.

```
SELECT t1.latitude, t2.longitude, t1.weight - t2.weight AS weight
FROM (SELECT latitude, longitude, SUM(weight) AS weight
      FROM points
      WHERE date = '2015-08-02'
      GROUP BY latitude, longitude) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT latitude, longitude, SUM(weight) AS weight
     FROM points
      WHERE date = '2015-08-03'
      GROUP BY latitude, longitude) AS t2
ON t1.latitude = t2.latitude AND t1.longitude = t2.longitude
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT 1
```